# using C function from other package in Rcpp

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp

I'm trying to call a C routine from the cubature package in a c++ function to perform multidimensional integration.

The basic R example I'm trying to reproduce is

```
library(cubature)
integrand <- function(x) sin(x)
adaptIntegrate(integrand, 0, pi)
```

I could just call this R function from Rcpp following [this recipe from the gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/), but there would be some performance penalty in switching back and forth from c/c++ to R. It seems more sensible to directly call the C function from C++.

The C routine `adapt_integrate` is exported from `cubature` with

```
 // R_RegisterCCallable("cubature", "adapt_integrate", (DL_FUNC) adapt_integrate);
```

I don't understand how to call it from c++, however. Here's my lame attempt,

```
sourceCpp(code = '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double integrand(double x){
 return(sin(x));
}

// [[Rcpp::depends(cubature)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List integratecpp(double llim, double ulim)
{
  Rcpp::Function p_cubature = R_GetCCallable("cubature", "adapt_integrate");

  Rcpp::List result = p_cubature(integrand, llim, ulim);
  return(result);
}
'
)

integratecpp(0, pi)
```

This fails to compile; clearly I'm doing something very silly and missing some important steps to convert the output of `R_GetCCallable` into an `Rcpp::Function` (or call it directly?). I've read several related posts dealing with function pointers, but haven't seen an example using an external C function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately `cubature` does not ship the headers in `inst/include`, so you have to borrow that from them and do something like this in your code:

```
typedef void (*integrand) (unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *,
           unsigned fdim, double *fval);

int adapt_integrate(
    unsigned fdim, integrand f, void *fdata,
    unsigned dim, const double *xmin, const double *xmax, 
    unsigned maxEval, double reqAbsError, double reqRelError, 
    double *val, double *err)
{
    typedef int (*Fun)(unsigned,integrand,void*,unsigned,
        const double*,const double*, unsigned, double, double, double*, double*) ;
    Fun fun = (Fun) R_GetCCallable( "cubature", "adapt_integrate" ) ;           
    return fun(fdim,f,fdata,dim,xmin,xmax,maxEval,reqAbsError, reqRelError,val,err); 
}
```

It might be a good idea to negociate with the maintainer of `cubature` that he ships declarations in `inst/include` so that you'd only have to use `LinkingTo`.

Comment: Many thanks for assembling these missing pieces. I will have to rethink the problem, unfortunately, because from what I see `adapt_integrate` will not easily accept an integrand that I defined using armadillo's data structures. For completeness, would you be able to add a minimal example of use?

Comment: What it gives you is access to the function pointer that `cubature` registered. I don't know what you are then supposed to do with the C function...

Comment: indeed, [considering an example of use](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature#Example) I see trouble ahead: `adapt_integrate_v` expects pointers to objects such as `*fdata`, the integrand expects pointers such as `*fval`, while the arguments I really want to pass are e.g. `arma::colvec` objects. I don't think I'll be able to make a bridge between the two. I may have to stick with R-level interface, or implement my own 2D quadrature in c++.

Comment: Sure. I was only answering how to call this function. If you want to call it with some other data type, you have to either do some data conversion work or negociate another interface with the maintainer of `cubature`.

Answer (score 7):

Didn't see this question earlier, and it looks like @Romain addressed it.

For completeness, a working example of how to do this when all parties play along is provided by the `xts` and `RcppXts` packages.  In `xts`, we do this (for about ten functions) in the (source) file `inst/include/xtsAPI.h`:

```
SEXP attribute_hidden xtsLag(SEXP x, SEXP k, SEXP pad) {     
    static SEXP(*fun)(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP) = NULL;         
    if (fun == NULL)                                  
        fun = (SEXP(*)(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP)) R_GetCCallable("xts","lagXts");   
    return fun(x, k, pad);                               
}
```

along with the usual business of `R_registerRoutines` and `R_RegisterCCallable`.

In `RcppXts` this is picked up (in an Rcpp Module) as

```
function("xtsLag", 
         &xtsLag,    
         List::create(Named("x"), Named("k"), Named("pad")),   
         "Extract the coredata from xts object");
```

which works pretty well.  Someone reprimanded me to write the `xts` side more compactly (as the `if NULL` is spurious) which I will get to ... eventually.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, unfortunately this is a case where working out the proper glue between the two pieces of code would take me way more time and suffering than actually doing the calculations with the slower R implementation. I would otherwise consider linking directly to the original cubature code rather than through the R package, which is using an older version.

Answer (score 2):

This question is three years old now but I want to point out that multidimensional integration with Rcpp may be easier now that the RcppNumerical library is available:
https://github.com/yixuan/RcppNumerical

The routines for computing integrals are based on Thomas Hahn's Cuba package and are also available in the R2Cuba library on CRAN, so if you can accept using the Cuba routines over the function `adaptIntegrate()` from Cubature, this package may be of interest.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. However it's probably best to keep it as a comment, since the question wasn't specifically about integration, but rather about accessing a C function from another package. I do appreciate the link though, I ended up using my own copy of cubature, but this looks like a worthy alternative (particularly if one is already using Eigen, but I'm used to Armadillo). One advantage of cubature though is the ability to deal with vector-valued integrands.