# Rcpp: Call C function from a package within Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I would like to write a C++ function with Rcpp that uses a **C** function found in the package *hypred*, which is on CRAN [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hypred/index.html).

I read [using C function from other package in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474303/using-c-function-from-other-package-in-rcpp), but don't understand if this applies for me and if it would apply, what to do.

The desired function is in the the source file */src/hypredRoutines.c* and is called *meiosisFUNAllChr*.

What I so far did based on this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474303/using-c-function-from-other-package-in-rcpp) is:

1. I separated the function *meiosisFUNAllChr* from the rest of the code and placed it in a new file called *meiosisFUNAllChr.c*.
2. I created a header file called *meiosisFUNAllChr.h* containing:

   ```
   #ifndef MEIOSISFUNALLCHR_H
   #define MEIOSISFUNALLCHR_H
   void meiosisFUNallChr (...);
   #endif
   ```
3. Compiled it with

   ```
   gcc -c -o meiosisFUNAllChr.o meiosisFUNAllChr.c
   ```
4. Created a dummy c++ function

   ```
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   using namespace Rcpp;

   extern "C" {
    #include "meiosisFUNallChr.h"
   }

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   int timesTwo(int x) {
    return x * 2;
   }
   ```

At this point, compiling with sourceCpp does not work. Can you show me how to get it working?

Many Thanks!

**EDIT**

Compiling with sourceCpp gives me:

```
meiosisFUNallChr.h: file or directory not found
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in Rcpp, but I found RStudio to be very helpful since it provides templates for it. When you create a project, you can specify that it uses Rcpp and it simplifies things a lot.

Comment: I know these facilities and already used them, but I don't know how this will help me to get the C function working in my code :-)

Comment: have you tried using `sourceCpp`?

Comment: @DominicComtois Yes, I did

Comment: Ok... when you say it doesn't work, what do you get? An error message? Or the function is just not available?

Comment: @DominicComtois I included it in an edit.

Comment: Are you trying to source the .h file? If yes, try rather with the .cpp file.

Comment: @DominicComtois I'm sourcing the .cpp. file.

Comment: I tried fiddling with it for a while, without any luck. Maybe try to get in touch with the _hypred_ package's author...?

Answer (score 3):

`hypred` registers its two functions, at the R level you can get hold of the one you want like this:

```
xp <- getDLLRegisteredRoutines( getLoadedDLLs()[["hypred"]] )[[".C"]][["meiosisFUNallChr"]]$address
```

I believe you can then access the function pointer in C++ like this:

```
DL_FUNC meiosisFUNallChr = reinterpret_cast<DL_FUNC>( R_ExternalPtrAddr(xp) ) ;
```

But you'd be better off negotiating with the package authors that they implement [this scheme](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages) if you can make a case that you really need to be calling the C function directly.

Comment: +1 regarding the registration scheme -- there are a few package in the Rcpp universe that do this. My simplest is probably RApiSerialize.  @romain:  is the `getDLLRegisteredRoutine(...)` approach "blessed" (or at least tolerated) by CRAN, ie is that what you used for mlxR?

Comment: no idea. I don't see why not though, I'm only calling allowed R functions `getDLLRegisteredRoutines` and `getLoadedDLLs` ... `mlxR` is an entirely different kind of bird

Comment: Yes, quite a different bird -- not a library under R's control.  Is there something genralizable from what you did?  We may have a similar issue with Rblpapi.

Comment: What we used is perhaps not ideal for distribution. essentially none of the code or the examples directly refer to the underlying c++ library. The user is supposed to have installed some software first, and mlxR compiles an R package from that software at runtime, so CRAN does not need to know about that software ...

Answer (score -1):

Briefly:

- You want to use another source file (presumably available under a suitable license).
- You want to call it from a new file of yours.
- So you already have *two* files.

By now the alarm bells should go off that *you really, really, want to create a package*.

Which the Rcpp documentation details in *many* places.  And there are 340+ packages on CRAN using Rcpp, many doing this very issue of calling a C file too.  Pick one or two, study their structure; also pick one or two created by the *fully documented Rcpp tools* such as `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and things should become a lot clearer.

*Edit:* Obviously, this approach only needs to be taken if the other package does not export its function. If you can get its author to export, use that as mention in Romain's answer.  Pairs of packages that export/use are zoo/xts, xts/RcppXts, expm/RcppKalman (not on CRAN), RApiSerialize/RcppRedis, ...

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I will do as you suggested.