# Use directly the cpp_ functions of extraDistr in the C++ code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Using the package `R::extraDistr` I noticed that many R functions of this package just call some cpp functions that do exactly the same work. For example, writing the command `dtnorm`, that gives us the density function of the truncated Normal distribution, we obtain in console

```
function (x, mean = 0, sd = 1, a = -Inf, b = Inf, log = FALSE) 
{
   cpp_dtnorm(x, mean, sd, a, b, log[1L])
}
<environment: namespace:extraDistr>
```

and so it seems that the R function just calls the respective c++ version, that is called `cpp_dtnorm`.

Since I'm writing the C++ and I need to use some of the functions included in this package, are there some ways to call directly the cpp_ functions without passing through the "R versions"?

Maybe it should be sufficient to find the script with the cpp_ function in the package directory, copy the code of interest and paste it into my script, but actually I do not know where I can find it. Can you help me in some ways?

Thank you all.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/extraDistr/blob/master/src/truncated-normal-distribution.cpp

Comment: Is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474303/using-c-function-from-other-package-in-rcpp) or [this chapter from Hadley Wickham's R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#cpp) -- specifically the "Importing C++ code" subsection -- helpful?

Comment: Not unless the other package exports it.  This really is a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I found your link very useful and it is exactly what I'm searching for. However, trying to compile the code I noticed that the file "shared.h" doesn't exist. How to deal with this? Thank you

Comment: The file is found in the repository as well.