# Using geos inside a Rcpp function

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, rcpp, geos

Anyone have a hint in how to use geos inside Rcpp functions (I'm building an R package)? 
Actually, I'm looking for a better approach then this:

```
Rcpp::Environment rgeos_env = Environment::namespace_env("rgeos");
Rcpp::Function Dist = rgeos_env["gDistance"];
```

Contextualizing, I want to calculate distances between spatial polygons, but I do that a lot of times (*Monte Carlo Tests*) and I want to improve the speed of my code.

Comment: You will not gain any speed up calling an _R_ function from _Rcpp_. This is because you have to _stop_ the _C++_ execution, pass objects back to _R_, run the _R_ function, export the results back into _C++_, and then finish the computation. Overall, there is a lot more overhead for little gain.

Comment: Have you tried using the `sf` package which uses `geos` to do spatial calculations?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, I tried last year, but it was slower than what I had. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It is a _qualitative_ duplicate in the sense that you cannot possibly envision Monte Carlo replications around _calling an R function_ from C++ and somehow betting on the magic pony to make it faster than R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible approaches to use geos without going back to R from C++:

- Try to link with the rgeos package, c.f. [using C function from other package in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474303/using-c-function-from-other-package-in-rcpp)
- Do what the rgeos package does, i.e. link with the geos library and call the relevant functions, c.f. https://github.com/cran/rgeos/blob/28403d4d4adbc3bd76c11e4c55dec7e097d74f6d/src/rgeos_misc.c#L50

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, it was very helpful.